# Pandas: pivot dataframe and preserve additional non-numeric column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I have some data in a list format: figures for 150-odd organisations, with a figure for each of a 12-month series. In its raw form it looks like this:

```
Name Size   Date  Figure
Org1 Medium Jun16 8.36
Org1 Medium Jul16 7.55
Org1 Medium Aug16 8.57
...
Org1 Medium May17 9.41
Org2 Large  Jun16 12.12
Org2 Large  Jul16 11.44
...
```

So each organisation has a unique name, twelve months of data, and one of three sizes (small, medium, large). I've successfully pivoted these figures to give me a timeseries for each organisation, i.e.,

```
Name Jun16 Jul16 Aug16 Sep16 Oct16...
Org1 8.36  7.55  8.57  7.66  9.43
Org2 12.12 11.44 11.01 12.01 10.44...
```

But I want to include another column containing the size of each organisation. The code I've used for the pivot is:

```
dataPivot = dataRaw.pivot_table(index='Name', columns ='Date'],
                              aggfunc='sum', values = 'Figure').fillna(0)
```

where `dataRaw` is the raw data read in from a .csv. I've tried adding `'Size'` to the `columns` field, but this just gives me 12 additional columns for each size!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing that is by using concat after creating a new df based on size i.e

```
table = df.pivot_table(index='Name', columns ='Date', aggfunc='sum', values = 'Figure').fillna(0)

size = df.groupby('Name').size().to_frame().rename(columns={0:'size'})

ndf = pd.concat([table,size],1)
```

Output based on sample data:

```
    Aug16  Jul16  Jun16  May17  size
Name                                  
Org1   8.57   7.55   8.36   9.41     4
Org2   0.00  11.44  12.12   0.00     2
```

If you mean to add Size column preset in the dataframe then add that column name to index parameter not columns i.e

```
df.pivot_table(index=['Name','Size'], columns =['Date'],aggfunc='sum', values =['Figure','Size']).fillna(0).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
    Name    Size Figure                    
Date                Aug16  Jul16  Jun16 May17
0     Org1  Medium   8.57   7.55   8.36  9.41
1     Org2   Large   0.00  11.44  12.12  0.00
```

Comment: Thank you, that's really close to what I'm after! I probably should have been a little clearer - I'd like the output to have the size of the organisation ("Medium", "Large", "Small") in the last column, instead of the count. Can I change the second line in your code to achieve this?

Comment: Is my edited answer what you are looking after? What a coincidence in updating and commenting haha

Comment: Yes, that's perfect. Thank you very much!